# phone portrait format to landscape format

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

What do I do if I have a video made by a smartphone while holding it upright, resulting in a portrait format, and I want it to be a landscape format like another video I want to combine, editing in Kdenlive 19.12.2?

Thanks in advance, Frank

Comment: When exporting, try to change the resolution to 1920x1080 instead of 1080x1920, effectively cropping in. If you have the option, try to crop the image, which will discard the parts of the video to the left and the right, to pick out the landscape part in the middle. If you want black bars around the horizontal video, you should be able to set the option of zooming or scaling, instead of cropping.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianClaaßen how do I change the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1080x1920 in Kdenlive? I couldn't find it on internet.

Comment: I am sorry but that I don't know neither.. there should be documentation on the program though, right? If not, I'd recommend switching to a more well-known and well-documented program such as Premiere, Vegas, etc...